# Using the Law of Cosines and SSA Congruence to show that a side is uniquely determined

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Let $JK = x$, $KL = y$, and $\angle J = \theta.$ Using the values for  of $x, y,$ and $\theta$, the third side, $JL$, can be uniquely determined.

Using the quadratic polynomial find conditions on $x, y$, and $\theta$ that guarantee that the side $JL$ is uniquely determined.

I found the quadratic polynomial for $JL$ by doing this:

I set $JL$ = side $z$, then used the Law of Cosines to get the quadratic polynomial $z^2-2xz-\frac{y^2-x^2}{cos \theta} = 0$. What does "showing that a side is uniquely determined" mean? How can I use the polynomial to show that the side is uniquely determined? Hints only please.

Comment: You should show that your quadratic polynomial will have either two equal positive roots or only one positive root. Start with the discriminant of the quadratic.

Comment: @AnuragA: The discriminant is: $4x^2+\frac{4y^2-4x^2}{cos \theta}$.

Comment: @AnuragA: I believe the discriminant is positive and has two real solutions.

Comment: @AnuragA: If they are positive, I think it would mean that there are two positive, real, unequal roots. But for there to be only one positive root, the discriminant would have to equal 0. Please advise.

Comment: @AnuragA: if the discriminant were to equal 0, y would have to equal 0, so it would not work. Two equal positive roots, then?

Comment: Well it doesn't uniquely determine the third side, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Your quadratic equation should instead be

$z^2-2xz\cos \theta + (y^2-x^2) = 0$

Thus, your discriminant should then instead be $4y^2 \cos^2 \theta – 4(1) (y^2 –x^2)$

Setting it to $0$ for equal roots (for uniquely determined line) and eventually you will get $\frac {x}{y} = \sin \theta$

This means……